# (nvim-treesitter) How to disable hyperlink highlighting in tree-sitter-markdown?

Tags: neovim, filetype-markdown, plugin-treesitter

I installed [`tree-sitter-markdown`](https://github.com/MDeiml/tree-sitter-markdown) in my `nvim` for editing the `md` files. However, it seems it highlights the links and hides the `url` part. This often annoys me when I edit `url`/`paths`.

You can see it in the below image.

[image]

- **Question**: Is it possible to configure it such that:

  - every other highlighting enabled / works as intended
  - but only the `link-highlighting` is disabled (or at least `url` part isn't hided by default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following Vim Command:

```
set cole=0
```

Comment: Do not hésitante to explain the rational behind your solution. It help others to understand it :-)

Comment: The option is `conceallevel`, I believe. Spelling it out is better for future readers.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble you are RIGHT !!!, setting `conceallevel` (from `0` to `2`) toggles it